Is there a formula for the probability of values of two polynomials to be relatively prime?
Let $\Delta(n)$ be the probability that the determinants of two randomly chosen $n \times n$ square integer matrices be relatively prime. We know that  $\Delta(1) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \Delta(n) = 0.3532363719... $.
I am interested in a similar subject to study about polynomials but I couldn't find anything useful on the web. For starters, given two random polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with integer coefficients but with the same degree what is the probability that for the same $n$, $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ will be relatively prime? More importantly, how does this probability change if the entry value (i.e. $n$) changes? Any useful suggestion would be much appreciated.

How is $n$ used in the definition of $\Delta(n)$?

@VezenBU, I edited thanks for pointing that out

It's not clear what a "random polynomial" means.  The distribution you choose might make a difference.

@lulu, any two distinct polynomials with integer coefficients are called randomly chosen, am I right?

No.  "random" requires a probability distribution.  In your case, the most natural one is:  pick a large integer $N$ and take a uniform distribution on all polynomials of degree $d$ with coefficients $a_i$ which satisfy $|a_i|≤N$.  Then, after you have solved that, try to let $N$ go to $\infty$.
